# Factory stub not working with angularjs mocha and sinon

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I'm running into problems using sinon to stub a factory while testing my controller. 
I'm using mocha, chai and sinon on top of angularjs.

Basically, I have a Classrooms factory that I'd like to stub and spy on, while I'm testing my controller.

Here's my controller code:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('ClassroomsCtrl', function ($scope, Classrooms){

  function init(){
    $scope.classrooms = Classrooms.search();
  }

  init();

});
```

Here's my factory code:

```
angular.module('app').factory('Classrooms', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/classrooms/:id', {
    id: '@id'
  },
  {
    search: {
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/classrooms/search',
      isArray: true
    }
  });
});
```

And here's my controller unit test:

```
angular.module('MyAppMocks',[]).
  factory('Classrooms', function(){
    return {
      search: sinon.stub()
    }
  });


describe('Controller: ClassroomsCtrl', function () {

  var scope, Classrooms, controllerFactory, spy;

  function createController() {
    return controllerFactory('ClassroomsCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      Classrooms: Classrooms
    });
  }

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(module('MyAppMocks'));


  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _Classrooms_){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    Classrooms = _Classrooms_;

    controllerFactory = $controller;

  }));


  it('should call Classrooms.search', function(){
    createController();
    expect(Classrooms.search).to.have.been.called();
  });

});
```

When I run my spec, I'm getting this error:

```
✗ should call Classrooms.search
    TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating 'expect(Classrooms.search).to.have.been.called()')
        at /Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/test/spec/controllers/classrooms.js:43
        at callFn (/Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4338)
        at /Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4331
        at /Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4728
        at /Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4819
        at next (/Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4653)
        at /Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4663
        at next (/Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4601)
        at /Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4625
        at done (/Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4300)
        at callFn (/Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4343)
        at /Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4331
        at next (/Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4626)
        at /Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4625
        at done (/Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4300)
        at callFn (/Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4343)
        at /Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4331
        at next (/Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4626)
        at /Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4625
        at done (/Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4300)
        at callFn (/Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4343)
        at /Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4331
        at next (/Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4626)
        at /Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4630
        at timeslice (/Users/tc/Documents/code/sandbox/edumatcher/ng-app/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:5763)
```

It seems like I have the stubbed Classrooms factory injected right, but something's not working with sinon. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Well, I've just switched over to using jasmine, since I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on. Still would be interested in any advice if anyone can see what's going on. Seems to be pretty straight forward in jasmine. No problems so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is it but what if you change

```
expect(Classrooms.search).to.have.been.called();
```

to

```
expect(Classrooms.search).to.have.been.called;
```

Noticed when using chai (BDD style, fwiw) that those weren't functions, just properties. Silly BDD. :)

Comment: Haha, I forgot I asked this question. Yes, that is indeed the problem.